# Why am I seeing START_REPLICATION 0/42000000 TIMELINE 1 Query in Postgresql 12

Tags: postgresql, replication

I am using Postgres 12 and have a master and slave setup. I am also running Barman on our secondary server in the meantime.

When looking in pg_stat_activity I see:

```
START_REPLICATION 0/42000000 TIMELINE 1
```

I have my wal_level set to logical and archive_mode set to on but am confused why I am seeing this in pg_stat_activity.

This server is new and has no traffic going on it at the moment, is this the reason why I am seeing the message? Am trying to find out online some information surrounding this but have had no joy.

If I run ps -eaf|grep postg|grep stream I do see that it is streaming.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain why this activity surprises you? Expected command for walsender, which can also be seen in pg_stat_activity nowadays (check backend_type)

Comment: @Melkij I have another environment which also runs postgres 12 (although I believe 12.5 vs 12.8) and dont see this query for the older version of postgres (12.5).

Answer (score 1):

I found a good explanation on:

- [Heroku Help: What are the long-running processes running START_REPLICATION queries on my Heroku Postgres database?](https://help.heroku.com/E70XCRPW/what-are-the-long-running-processes-running-start_replication-queries-on-my-heroku-postgres-database)

TLDR:
PostgreSQL 13.4, 12.8, 11.13, 10.18: walsender processes show their latest replication commands in pg_stat_activity. Filter out with `WHERE backend_type = 'walsender'`.